# Folder and Files read write permission in production environment for an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I have taken an hosting account and uploading the files. Before working it out, i want to learn about the permissions for files and folders that are needed to be set.

The application resides in the root folder. It uses SQL CE as a database whose .sdf file is saved in App_data folder. Do i need to set read and write permission for this file ? Also, I have a folder named *Images*, which will save the uploaded files by user. I have set the read and write permission for this folder

One other thing, i can't understand is the existence of two App_Data folders : One in root and one in bin. Can i delete anyone of these or let them be as they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running your app? You may find you don't need to set any permissions.

You'd really be better asking these questions to your Hosting Provider.